# Size of icon in SwitchPreference

Tags: android-studio, android-preferences

I want to change the size of the icon in SwitchPreference

```
        <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="Key"
        anroid:icon ="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout="@layout/preference_item_normal"
        android:title="Title" />
```

It should have size 48*48. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the size of your icon file to 48x48. With any image manipulation tool.

Comment: picture quality deteriorates

Comment: yes but this will always be the problem if the origin image is to small. Could you create a bigger base image?

Comment: Oh okay, but than the icon has to loose quality because it is shown so much smaller. But this won't be visible in the app.